# default input border shows differently on div

Tags: html, css

If I create an input box without any styles (`<input>`) and then inspect the computed css in devtools I see it has border 2px inset rgb(238, 238, 238)

However if I create a div with the same border it looks very different:

```html
<input>
<br><br>
<div style="border: 2px inset rgb(238, 238, 238); height:15px; width: 169px; "></div>
```

Why is that ? and what kind of border will give me the same one as the input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK fount it

input has the -webkit-appearance:textfield; style on it

```css
div {
  border: 2px inset;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  height: 15px;
  width: 169px;
}
```

```html
<input>
<br><br>
<div></div>
```

Comment: If you want to use this on your website, better also include `appearance` (the non-prefixed version). You never know if this will one day be standardised, and then the prefixed version will stop working.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```html
<input>
<br><br>
<div style="border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); height:15px; width: 169px; "></div>
```

Comment: ok thx can you explain how did you get this and why devtools shows the wrong values ?

Comment: @kofifus Just by looking at the design of the input, then estimating the right color for the border. And I don't know why the devtool shows a different one

Comment: On my machine, the borders in the snippet are not identical; the bottom one is darker. So it depends on the platform and.or browser.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually a 2px border. If you change the background of the `input`, we can see the 2px border. See below with `background:#f1f1f1` for the input.

```html
<input style="background:#f1f1f1;">
<br><br>
<div style="border: 2px inset rgb(238, 238, 238); height:15px; width: 169px; "></div>
```

Comment: so how can I make my div look the same as the default input ? should I change it's background ? seem like they both have white background but the div shows the inset but the input don't

Answer (score 1):

This is more likely identical to your `<input>` style

```
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
height: 19px;
width: 171px;
```

inset - Defines a 3D inset border.

solid - Defines a solid border.

This is the main different in your style.